# raster::plotRGB() works, but tm_rgb() gives "error in ind[!isna] <- m2 NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments"

Tags: r, r-raster, tmap

I'm trying to use a large geoTIFF as a basemap for a plot. The image is available through [Harvard's online library](http://hgl.lib.harvard.edu:8080/opengeoportal/)

I can successfuly import it with the raster package and plot it like so:

```
mke.raster <- raster::brick("path/to/image-geo.tif")
raster::plotRGB(mke.raster)
```

Here's what the output looks like at low resolution.
[image: output]

Unfortunately, this process fails with tmap. I tried,

```
tm_shape(mke.raster) +
  tm_rgb()
```

This gives the following error:

> Error in ind[!isna] <- m2 : 
>     NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Comment: What is the purpose of doing with tm? what is the overall objective of not using plotRGB

Comment: @DerekCorcoran, I'm trying to make a map with the tmap package, using this raster image as a basemap.